# AudioRecord: AudioFormat constants and microphone selection

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord, audioformat

I'm currently starting writing a software for Android which is about to measure the reverberation time of closed rooms.
I had to choose [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) instead of [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) because it gives me the chance to get the raw data.
You may know that there are many different constant to choose from for the `AudioFormat` (e.g.: `CHANNEL_IN_MONO`, `CHANNEL_IN_STEREO`, `CHANNEL_IN_PRESSURE`) and you may know that in android smartphones there are more than just one microphone embedded (usually you have 2 microphones in it, in order to have noise cancellation and stuff like that).

Here comes the question: Which constant do I have to choose to be sure that only just ONE microphone is giving me the raw data?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a mono recording the device should only be recording from one microphone. I'm not sure what you mean by "raw" data. There will always be some acoustic compensation processing done (e.g. automatic gain control, equalization, etc), and this is not something that you can turn off.

One thing that also will affect the recording is which [AudioSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) you choose. If you select CAMCORDER on a phone with 2 or more microphones you'll typically get the back microphone with far-field tuning if you do a mono recording. If you select MIC/DEFAULT you should get the primary mic, but it may be tuned for either near-field recording or far-field recording depending on the vendor (I suspect that you'd want far-field tuning if you're trying to measure room reverberation).

Comment: Sorry, raw data for me means uncompressed .wav samples. I know that unfortunately there are some kind of automatic controls always ON. I also noticed very very different behaviours between different android devices: HTC have the worst AGC I've ever seen, it's impossible to do any audio-pro application with those devices. Thank you anyway for your near-field/far-field explanation, very useful